# calculating missing sprites in cocos2d

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocos2d-iphone

i want to calculate the missing sprites.

for example:-  random generated sprites is displaying in the screen. i want to shoot the sprites. if shooted means sprite disappeared. if i missed one sprite. missed sprite count is more than 10 means "game over".

here is my code for shooting sprites:-

```
- (void)update:(ccTime)dt {
    NSMutableArray *targetsToDelete = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    for (_sprite in _targets) {
    CGRect spriteRect = CGRectMake(
                                   _sprite.position.x - (_sprite.contentSize.width/2), 
                                   _sprite.position.y - (_sprite.contentSize.height/2), 
                                   _sprite.contentSize.width, 
                                   _sprite.contentSize.height);
    if(CGRectContainsPoint(spriteRect, location)) 
            {
                _sprite.isTouched = YES;
                [targetsToDelete addObject:_sprite];
                spritedestroyed++;                  

                if (spritedestroyed >= 50) {

                    GameOverScene *gameOverScene = [GameOverScene node];
                    [gameOverScene.layer.label setString:@"You Win!"];
                    [[CCDirector sharedDirector] replaceScene:gameOverScene];
                }

            }
    }   


    for (_sprite in targetsToDelete) {
            [_targets removeObject:_sprite];
            [self removeChild:_sprite cleanup:YES]; 
        }
        [targetsToDelete release];


}
```

how to calculate the missing sprites ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use a variable.. when new sprite is created, the variable will +1 and when any target is destroyed, use -1 then when the number is more than 10, game over..

Comment: its working, but i dont want to calculate some unwanted sprites displayed on the screen.  now caluclate dthat unwanted sprites

Comment: create 2 arrays then..
when init, store all object in 1 array.. when being touched, remove the object from the current array and add to the TargetToDelete array..